# Simple pagination function with Swift 4

Tags: swift, function, pagination

I need help with a pagination function, for example i have a endpoint that contain 1624 items, but only fecth a total of 100 per call.

So i need a function with 2 parameters, totalItems and paginationLenght, so if i pass 1624 and 100 and this function return array or dict with this data, for example:

```
[1, 100]
[101, 200]
[201, 300]
...
[1601, 1624]
```

PD: I use Swift 4. Help will be apreciated.

Comment: My guess would be you got down voted because the title is not very clear, the question is not very specific and you appear to just be requiring someone to write a function to do something for you.  Have you tried to do it?  If so what have you tried?  If not what is stopping you?

Comment: I don't need any code (i code by myself), i only need mathematic, stend how to achieve this...

Comment: Taken from here: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172820/paginaci%C3%B3n-con-swift/172838

Comment: No you needed code.  That other answer gives you code.  This is also a programming/coding site for questions about programming/coding.  If you just wanted the mathematics of it you can ask on a more appropriate site.  Any way it wasn't me that down voted I was just trying to be helpful and suggest reasons why it might have been.  The unhelpful title alone is enough for someone to down vote the question.

Comment: Thanks, i will have that in count.

Comment: Yeah, i'm looking for some general formula or somethink like that. But this Question/Answer can help some one in the future, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is:

```
var pages = [[Int]]()
let totalItems = 1624
let pageSize = 100
let segments = totalItems / pageSize

for i in 0...segments {
    let step = i * pageSize
    let start = step + 1
    let end = step + pageSize
    pages.append([start, min(end, totalItems)])
}

print(pages)
```